# how can i use 'withevents' with array class in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

ex)
 Public WithEvents g_StateMsgHandler() As New CStateMsg

In my code, array class (g_StateMsgHandler) can't use 'withEvents'

how can i change my code to use eventhandler in CStateMsg class?

not use individual withevents class like g_StateMsgHandler_1, g_StateMsgHandler_2

Comment: That doesn't make sense, System.Array does not raise events.  If the array *elements* can raise an event then you must use the [AddHandler statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement) to subscribe events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You can only declare a field `WithEvents` if the type of the variable actually has events. An array has no events so declaring it `WithEvents` is nonsensical. If what you actually want to do is handle an event of each element in the array then you're not handling an event of the array so it is doubly nonsensical.

If you want to handle an event of each element in an array then you have two choices. You can either declare a field for each element, declaring them all `WithEvents` and including them all in the same `Handles` clause, or you can loop through the array and use `AddHandler` to register each event handler.  If you have a method like this:

```
Private Sub HandleSomEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    '...
End Sub
```

then you can do this:

```
For Each element In my Array
    AddHandler element.SomeEvent, AddressOf HandleSomeEvent
Next
```

If you do that, be sure to use `RemoveHandler` when you're done handling the events:

```
For Each element In my Array
    RemoveHandler element.SomeEvent, AddressOf HandleSomeEvent
Next
```